# Will Milky Way photos show too much grain when printed at 12×18"?

Tags: printing, astrophotography, canvas

I want to print out either of these two Milky Way Photos on a 12x18 size photograph (Or vice versa if it is horizontal).

- http://500px.com/photo/77785439/milky-way-touching-the-trees-by-tom-jones
- http://500px.com/photo/77522361/milky-way-over-sprague-lake-by-tom-jones

The problem I'm worried about is the amount of grain which would show up.  The photos look fine on my laptop (MBP Retina) but I'm not sure about them being almost twice the size.  Due to them being astro photos, grain is just part of their nature.  Even with stacking etc.  I've never printed a photo this large before and do not want to spend all the money to have it show up with a lack of detail.  Do any of you have any advice for printing them? I'd appreciate any ideas.  (Photoshop, printing services, canvas vs paper)

Comment: Are they your images?  What resolution are they?

Comment: Yes they are my images, 3456 × 5184 pixels

Comment: What about making a small crop sample, but with the intended scale, and printing that first? This should give you an impression of how the final one would look like.

Comment: In regard to printing, you may need to adjust some contrast to have it match your intent.  You are only seeing these on your MBP, but the print doesn't have a back light to make the stars pop.  So, you may need to increase the micro-contrast of the stars.  I agree with Dubu's comment - print a subsection/crop on a smaller piece of photo paper - I would also recommend printing on Glossy photo paper for these (unless it's going to be framed behind glass).  Another trick to bring out certain details is to use appropriate color(s) of mat board(s).

Comment: If anything they will likely look _better_ printed than they do on screen. I would just print them out. A 12x18in printed image isn't typically viewed at the same distance as a laptop screen either(usually further away) so the viewing distance should work to your advantage too.

Comment: 5184 pixels across 18 inches is nearly 300 ppi. Stop worrying.

Comment: One experiment is worth 1000 expert opinions.— Bill Nye, the science guy Go ahead, enlarge a small portion (read inexpensively) of your image to see what you will get.

Comment: Digital shots never have grain - that's a film thing.  But I don't expect the noise (which is what it is here) to be objectionable at that print size.